# django class-based view unexpected keyword argument

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I had a legacy code:

my url:

```
url(r'^check_unique_username/(?P<field_value>(.*?){1,150})/$',
        auth.views.check_unique_username, name='check_unique_username'),
```

my view:

```
 def check_unique_username(request, field_value):
        return HttpResponse(check_unique_filed_value(request, "username", field_value))
```

which works perfectly with `localhost:8000/check_unique_username/myusername`

but now I want to make it class-based:

url:

```
url(r'^check_unique_username/(?P<field_value>(.*?){1,150})/$',
        auth.views.CheckUniqueUsername.as_view(), name='check_unique_username'),
```

view:

```
class CheckUniqueUsername(APIView):

    def get(self):
        return HttpResponse(CheckUniqueFieldValue.check_uniqueness("username", self.request.get('username')))
```

that raises

`TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'`

what should I do? tnx

---

***update:***
I changed my view to:

```
class CheckUniqueUsername(APIView):

    def get(self):
        return HttpResponse(CheckUniqueFieldValue.check_uniqueness("username", self.kwargs['field_value']))
```

but still getting the error
`TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field_value'`

Comment: This is not part of `self.request`. It is part of `self.kwargs`, and the field name is *here* `field_name`. so `self.kwargs['field_name']`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem would you please check my post update?

Comment: As an aside, using class-based views doesn't mean you need to make everything a class. Using classmethods as you do with `CheckUniqueFieldValue.check_uniqueness` is not very Pythonic. It would make sense though if you made `check_uniqueness` a method on the view itself, then you could just call it via `self.check_uniqueness`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for your advice, I would take it into consideration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These URL parameters are stored in `self.kwargs`, so you can access these with `self.kwargs['field_name']`. But these parameters are - by default - also passed to the `get`, `post`, etc. functions. So you need to catch these (and optionally ignore):

```
class CheckUniqueUsername(ApiView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse(
            CheckUniqueFieldValue.check_uniqueness("username", self.kwargs['field_name'])
        )
```

*Unnamed* parameters are stored in `self.args`. You can thus see a class-based view as some sort of function with `def view(request, *args, **kwargs)` that stores the `args` and `kwargs` as attributes in the instance.

Or more convenient is directly use these:

```
class CheckUniqueUsername(ApiView):

    def get(self, request, *args, field_name=None, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse(
            CheckUniqueFieldValue.check_uniqueness("username", field_name)
        )
```